# C#: How to select the top item in a listview after sorting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm filling my System.Windows.Forms.ListView with results from my database as such:

```
foreach (DataRow row in theTable.Rows)
{
    ...build item from row..

    myListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

And then I want to sort my listview in a different order than the rows come back from the DB, so I call

```
myListView.Sort();
```

But then when I want to go to select the top item in the listview it won't work, it selected something other than the top item:

```
myListView.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Makes sense since the Items collection is added to in the order of the rows from the table iterated through in the foreach loop.

Using myListView.TopItem.Seleted = true doesn't work either.

So how do I go about selecting the topmost item in the listview AFTER I've sorted it?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Sort DataTable before adding items...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the list view is currently selected? If it's not selected you will not see the item being selected.

The following code seem to be working:

```
    private void Populate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        listView1.Items.Add("D");
        listView1.Items.Add("B");
        listView1.Items.Add("A");
        listView1.Items.Add("C");
    }

    private void SelectFirst(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        listView1.Select();
    }

    private void SortAndSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        listView1.Sort();

        listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        listView1.Select();
    }
```

Notice the listView1.Select()

Comment: I'm trying the above code on a blank form right now and D is being selected, which is the problem that I'm describing in my original post.
I'm wondering about a way for it to come away with A selected here...

Comment: After you call SortAndSelect - D is still selected? What .NET Version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, see screenshots below. (Iflipped the order of the list a bit from yours so it selects C) Using VS2005 .NET2

http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f38/ZGangsta/Untitled3.png
http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f38/ZGangsta/Untitled.png

Comment: Hmm, it works now in Form_Load.

In my actual code I'm doing this called from an Initialize function I've set up which is being called between the Form's initialization and its ShowDialog call...

Any idea why the difference?

Comment: The form layout must occur before you can play with all the controls. I'm not sure on the details, but I think it occurs only after the constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623808/form-constructor-vs-form-load

Answer (score 1):

You probably have HideSelection set to true. Make it false, and try.

```
myListView.HideSelection = false;
```

Furthermore listviews can have a selected item but with no focus on some other item. So its better to set both focus and selection together:

```
if (myListView.Items.Count > 0)
{
    myListView.Items[0].Selected = true;
    myListView.Items[0].Focused = true;
}
```

If that doesn't work you can set focus to listview itself to see if selection is falling on right item.

Comment: No, HideSelection is false in my code. I can see the item being selected. As I said, it's that it's selecting what was the top item when they were added to the list, not the top item after the sort.

Comment: @Luke are u sure you are calling the set focusing part after sorting?

Comment: Yes, after sorting. I fill the listview, sort, then set the selected/focused item to Items[0] and the top item in the list doesn't select, what selects is the first item that was added to the collection (which makes sense).
I'm not having a problem seeing the selection, what I'm wondering is how to select the item that is the top after the sort.

Comment: @Luke I tried your code and it worked for me very well. Something is strange in your case. It would be better to see a screenshot of your listview before and after sorting and setting of focus

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.

This is a simple example of the code (from Nitay's example below)
http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f38/ZGangsta/Untitled2.png

And this is a screenshot as soon as the form opens
http://i44.photobucket.com/albums/f38/ZGangsta/Untitled.png

So you can see how C is selecting when I want it to be A.

Comment: @Luke thats so strange. Doesnt happen with me. Your code in link gives me the correct selection of top item.

Comment: see bewlow in comments on Nitay's answer. It works for me if I move the code to Form_Load.